# Proving a solution is optimal without using simplex

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

Ok so we have the following linear programming problem :

maximize $  x_1+2x_2 - 3x_3 +x_4$

subject to  $x_1+x_2+x_3\le4 \\x_2-x_3+x_4\le3\\x_1-2x_2+2x_4\ge1
\\x_1,x_3,x_4\ge0\\x_2\ge2$

We are given a solution where $x_1=1,x_2=2,x_3=1,x_4=2 $. Is there a way to prove that its an optimal solution **without using simplex??** I am thinking about using the graph to find all the corner points,then confirm that the given values are indeed a corner point, and then prove that for these given values, the function is indeed maximized. But i am not sure.

Comment: Impossible. This solution is not feasible. You have a bound $x_3\ge 2$ and the solution has $x_3=1$.

Comment: Hint: Find the dual problem and then use the complementary slackness theorem to prove if it is an optimal solution. You can use the solution $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(2,0,2,5)$ as a start.

Comment: i am sorry its actually $x_2\ge2 $